# Send Apollo GraphQL mutation request from React to Contentful

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, contentful

I have a simple app built using React + contentful, I'm using apollo as a client.
I have a simple array of objects which I retrieve using query and which I'd like to update directly from UI.

this is my query

```
export const GET_RADIO = gql`
  query getUrl {
    allContentfulRadioUrl {
      nodes {
        url
        radioName
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

it works fine.

Then this is my mutation:

```
export const NEW_RADIO = gql`
  mutation addNewRadio($url: String!, $name: String!) {
    newRadio(url: $url, radioName: $name) {
      allContentfulRadioUrl {
        nodes {
          url
          radioName
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I'm passing the data to the mutation in this way:

```
  const [addRadio] = useMutation(NEW_RADIO);


  const submit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   
    addRadio({
      variables: { url: formState.url, radioName: formState.radioName },
    });
  };
```

but I keep having errors in the response:

> GraphQLError: Variable "$name" of required type "String!" was not provided."

It's my first time using GraohQL and this stack so I'm sure I'm missing something.
what do I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found out that the plugin gatsby-source-contentful is only for querying data and not for mutations, so i was trying to do something impossible